# Google Spreadsheet: Compare 2 arrays

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'd like your assistance in coming up with a formula that would compare 2 arrays:

`Array A:

444444

333333

222222



Array B

111111111

123124123

124124111

444444`

I would like to compare the 2 arrays and return how many values exist in both arrays.
So for these 2 arrays that appear on the top it should read 1 because only '444444' exists in both arrays.

The reason I'm speaking about arrays and not cells/columns/rows is because I use the =QUERY() function to get the arrays.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If all values in Array A are unique (or if you want to double-count duplicates etc):

`=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(Array_A;MATCH(Array_A;Array_B;0))))`

If you needed to account for non-unique values in Array A, and not double-count them:

`=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(UNIQUE(Array_A);MATCH(UNIQUE(Array_A);Array_B;0))))`

Comment: Nice, works well. Is there any reason why you use `;` as opposed to the more common `,` between arguments?

Comment: In Google Sheets, the comma delimiter between arguments is only supported in locales that do not use a comma as a decimal separator. However, a semi-colon is accepted as an argument delimiter in *all* locales. So I guess it has just become best practice in the Google Sheets community to use semi-colons.